# How can I upload a file to a particular google drive folder by name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a set of pdfs to google drive, I would like them to be sorted into various folders on google drive.

Right now I am uploading the files each with their own separate request in a for loop.

Is there a way to sort them into a file path like I would on my own filesystem?

for example: `` `certificates/${courseYear}/${courseName}` ``

Comment: You just need to set the parent folder when you upload each file.

Comment: The only reference I was able to find to setting parent folders used Id as opposed to folder name. What is the syntax for setting the parent folder by folder name?

Comment: it should be the folder id of the folder you want to upload to.  please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: So if the folder is named `certificates/${courseYear}/${courseName}` as in my example, the id would be that string?

Comment: What the file id of the folder is i cant tell you you would have to get the file id of courseName folder before uploading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file into a folder on Google Drive you must have the file id / folder Id of the parent folder you want to upload it into.  (Everything runs though file ids in google drive even a folder or directory is referred to as a file it just has a mime type of `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`)

Lets say i have the following directory structure.

```
Root
    - Cars (fileid: 123456)
```

The first thing you would need to do would be to create a new folder on Google drive called Cars.

```
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'cars'
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
};
drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});
```

Then to create to upload a file inside that folder  you set the parents value of the file id that you got from the folder you just created.

```
 var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'photo.jpg',
  'parents': file.id.fromprevouscall
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
  body: fs.createReadStream('files/photo.jpg')
};
drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});
```

Note: i am not a javascript developer I am just guessing at this code from the could on the [website](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads).   I am a .net developer but the API works the same for every language.

Comment: So I take it from your response that it is not possible to upload to a folder using something like a file path. I have to first search for the folder to get the id, then mark that as the parent folder in the upload?

Comment: no google drive only requires that you send the folder id as part of the request.  you could add the directory structure to the parent but again you need the id of the parent folder to upload it.

Answer (score -1):

Create and populate folders
Folders are files that only contain metadata and can be used to organize files in Google Drive. Specifically,

a folder is a file with the MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.folder and with no extension.
you can use the alias root to refer to the root folder anywhere a file ID is provided.
This guide explains how to perform some basic folder-related tasks.

Create a folder
To create a folder, use the files.create method with the application/vnd.google-apps.folder MIME type and a title. The following code snippet shows how to create a folder using a client library:
Insert a file in a folder
To insert a file in a folder, use the files.create method and specify the folder ID in the parents property of the file. The following code snippet shows how to insert (upload) a file into a specific folder using a client library:
The parents property can be used when creating a folder and subfolders.

Moving files between folders
To add or remove parents for an existing file, use files.update method with the addParents and removeParents query parameters. The following code snippet moves a file between folders using a client library::